# setrlimit doesn't work on OS X Maverick and Yosemite

Tags: c++, limit, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, ulimit

I work in company writing Audio Plugins for various programs, and currently I have the following problem with Logic on Os X Mavericks and Yosemite.
Logic scans all our plugins, and, at some point it can no longer access the files. The errno is 24, meaning "Too Many Open Files"

We have the following roows in our code, that increase file descriptors available:

```
struct rlimit limit;
if (::getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit) == 0)
{
    limit.rlim_cur = (in_maxOpenFiles);
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &SetLimit);
}
```

And I also tried:

```
struct rlimit limit;
if (::getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit) == 0)
{
    limit.rlim_cur = (in_maxOpenFiles);
    limit.rlim_max = (in_maxOpenFiles);
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &SetLimit);
}
```

Yet it did not help.
The funny thing is, that if I open terminal, and run the following command:

```
ulimit -n 1024
```

and then I run the Logic from WITHIN the terminal everything is fine and there is no descriptor problems!!

Now, I thought that setrlimit is suppose to do the same as setrlimit, no?
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I also tried this solution:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks

It did not help.

Comment: Did u tried `system("ulimit -n 1024");`

Comment: Yes. Didn't work. I guess calling it from within application is too late. It does not affect already running process.

Comment: Have you tried examining the return value of `setrlimit`? (I think there's a typo in "setrlimit is suppose to do the same as setrlimit" but I'm unable to guess what it is.)

Comment: Yes. The return value is always 0, meaning everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem in this article eventually:
http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X

Here is also solution (For Maverick, not Yosemite):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108174/how-to-persist-ulimit-settings-in-osx-mavericks

However, it is still unclear why **setrlimit** fails. Probably OS X bug (Or feature).

Answer (score -2):

The code above (1st variant) doesn't fail if there is no 3rd party software messing around w/ ulimit, launchctl limit maxfiles, etc. Reboot your mac and try again.

P.S. Let's not multiply such software
P.P.S check 'errno' variable for error code